# Vim exec command with input() and nested command

Tags: vim, eclim

I would like to create a vim command that is waiting for an input THEN that will execute ':cw' automatically after the first command.

Here is what I try:

```
noremap <C-p> :exec ":ProjectGrep /".input('Search: ')"/ src/**"<CR>:cw
```

But the ':cw' does not execute after the command, it complete the input().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your `vimrc` to make Vim open the quickfix/location window when there are valid errors/locations:

```
augroup qf
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l* lwindow
augroup END
```

That snippet addresses what I believe is your underlying issue (having the quickfix window open automatically after your search command), though, not your actual question.

Anyway, `cwindow` should be the last command in the function called by your `:ProjectGrep` command; not at the mapping level.

Comment: Thank you, it's more cleaner. I finaly made it by writing a function